# Mysql cluster + proxy - production architecture questions

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-cluster

I'm launching a big project of mine which took me more than a year.
if this work as I want, this would need a solid database architecture, but I'm a developer and kind of noob for database configuration.
Application is made with Spring/Mysql served with tomcat 8.
So after some research i've concluded this :

- I will use mysql cluser with InnoDB engine
- To start I need 3 server minimum for mysql clustering
- To handle this correctly I'll use ProxySQL to route correctly queries on right node

Left some question:

- How does replication works for migrations, if I want to add a column or a table does this replicates on all of nodes ?
- I want to take 3 more server on cloud to do this, how much ram is the best for this kind of use ?
- Is there better options ?

Comment: You should better be focusing on development for your application . I guess if you are asking about *how much memory* do you need, it means you can not estimate number of servers you need. So your estimation about 3 servers makes absolutely no sense at the moment. I would suggest to not care about cluster, ones you reach the real load  when single server can not handle - come back with real tests and questions

Comment: that's always a good idea for me to be one step ahead every time. That's why i prefer start to search for solutions before problem ;)
That's a point of view, and i don't think i need much test to know that a single server will not be able to work for a long time.

Comment: So how did you measure your load? why do you think 1 server (you have no hardware defined yet) can not handle the load? what is your forecast of load on sql? what was your biggest project you did on mysql? how did you measure the load? what kind of issues did you have there?

Comment: I didn't really measure but i know that this will not be enough at a moment... 
I do have experience more with SQL Server, the project can be called as a social plateform there will be a lot of request (discussions, notifications, etc...)
so yes the issue is to be prepared to migrate on a bigger architecture as soon as it's needed